# how to integrate jquery files with angular 4

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript

i am new to angular 4. i am calling a jquery function with html tag from a method. And that jquery method is defined in another file. so how to write those in angular?
this is the example

```
sample() {
  $.("represent-visualization").Sample();
}
```

And the function Sample is defined in a jquery file

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.sample()
    {
     }
 })(jquery);
```

Comment: take a look at this link [how to add external js in Angular with or wothout typings](https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/faq)

Comment: What are you trying to do? You shouldn't need to use jQuery within Angular, please provide more of your code.

Comment: instead of using jquery how can i use this by using simple functions?

Answer (score 1):

```
npm install jquery --save


npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Install jquery with npm

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Add typings

```
npm install --save-dev @types/jquery
```

Add scripts to angular-cli.json

when you cant to import

import * as jquery from "jquery";

`jquery.("represent-visualization").Sample();`

Comment: still i am not getting .. its giving an error saying some identifier is expected ..